# Laravel eloquent selecting most recent row from joined table

Tags: join, laravel, eloquent

I have two tables, Project and Projectnote

There is a one to many relationship between project and projectnote.

I want to be able to list my projects and select the most recent projectnotes based on the created_at date.

Is this possible to do in Eloquent, I can't figure it out.

Thanks for any help!

Edit: so far I have a basic query (below) that joins the two tables. However, this only selects projects where a note exists and I get multiple rows where there are several notes per project.

```
$projects = Project::join('projectnotes', 'projectnotes.project_id', '=', 'projects.id')
->select(array('projects.*', 'projectnotes.note as note'))
->get();
```

Comment: Yes, this is possible in Eloquent. What have you tried?

Comment: Edited in the above what I have so far

Comment: If you are trying to get X notes per project with eager loading, then it's impossible with Eloquent and pretty complex in SQL. Otherwise (meaning loading all related notes) simply `$projects = Project::with(['projectNotes'=>function($q){$q->latest();}])->get();` (or whatever the relation name it is instead of `projectNotes`)

Answer (score 16):

You can join the table on the latest value:

```
->join('t1', function($join) {
        $join->on('t1.t2_id', '=', 't2.id')
             ->on('t1.id', '=', DB::raw("(select max(id) from t1 WHERE t1.t2_id = t2.id)"));
```

If you also want to join where t1 does not have a value, use a leftJoin. In your case this would look like this:

```
$projects = Project::leftJoin('projectnotes', function($join) { 
        $join->on('projectnotes.project_id', '=', 'projects.id')
             ->on('projectnotes.id', '=', DB::raw("(SELECT max(id) from projectnotes WHERE projectnotes.project_id = projects.id)")); 
        })
        ->select(array('projects.*', 'projectnotes.note as note'))
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you try to order by id in that specific scenario; the below is my suggested solution for you based on your code:

```
$projects = Project::join('projectnotes', 'projectnotes.project_id', '=', 'projects.id')
    ->select(array('projects.*', 'projectnotes.note as note'))
    ->orderBy('projectnotes.id')
    ->latest('projectnotes.id')
    ->get()->unique();
```

The code above works on Laravel 5.6; your can try it out.

Answer (score 0):

In your project model, make the `notes` relationship function look something like:

```
public function notes() {
  return $this->hasMany('Note');
}
```

Then you can get the most recent Note of the Project with primary key 1 by chaining `orderBy` and `first`:

```
Project::find(1)->notes()->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->first();
```

Also, is your note table called 'Note' or 'Notes'? (Keeping with Laravel style, it should be named singular as I have it in this code)

Comment: Corrected the post to reflect the table names properly.

Comment: You need to correct this: `Project::find(1)->notes->orderBy...` to `..->notes()->orderBy..` otherwise this will call non existing `orderBy` method on the `Collection`