# Laravel Eloquent selecting field from relationship after joining with other tables

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a query where I have joined several tables together and as they have fields with identical names I have used the select query to only pick out the fields that I require. However, i also need to include the results obtained from the with query but I do not know how to specify it in the select query.

```
        $display_tickets = ManualTicket::select('u.name as name', 'i.name as initiator', 'manual_tickets.status as status', 'manual_tickets.description as description', 'manual_tickets.location as location', 'manual_tickets.created_at as created_at', 'manual_tickets.initiator_id as initiator_id', 'manual_tickets.id as manual_ticket_id','manual_tickets.manual_ticket_log as manual_ticket_log_id')
            ->leftJoin('users as u', 'u.id', '=', 'manual_tickets.user_id')
            ->leftJoin('users as i', 'i.id', '=', 'manual_tickets.initiator_id')
            ->where(function ($checkClients) use($target_client_id){
                $checkClients->where('u.client_id', '=', $target_client_id)
                    ->orWhere('i.client_id', '=', $target_client_id);
            })
            ->whereBetween('manual_tickets.created_at', [$start_date->toDateString(), $end_date->addDays(1)->toDateString()])
            ->with('manual_ticket_log')
            ->orderBy("created_at", "DESC")->get();
```

I tried to include the manual ticket logs through the use of the code below but it says that there is no such field in the manual ticket table.

```
'manual_tickets.manual_ticket_log as manual_ticket_log_id')
```

In short, how can i include the results of the with relationship from ->with('manual_ticket_log') into the select statement

--EDIT-- (Tried to replace join with with queries)

However there appears to be any error with my SQL query which i believe stems from the whereHas portion of the code which results in this error being shown.

***strtolower() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given***

```
 $display_tickets = ManualTicket::select('*')
                ->with('user')
                ->with('initiator')
                ->with('manual_ticket_log')
                ->where(function ($checkClients) use($target_client_id){
                    $checkClients->whereHas('user', function ($checkClient) use($target_client_id){
                        $checkClient->where('client_id', '=', $target_client_id);
                    })
                    ->orWhere($checkClients->whereHas('initiator', function ($checkClient2) use($target_client_id){
                        $checkClient2->where('client_id', '=', $target_client_id);
                    }));
                })
                ->whereBetween('manual_tickets.created_at', [$start_date->toDateString(), $end_date->addDays(1)->toDateString()])
                ->orderBy("created_at", "DESC")->get();
```

Comment: You can't and shouldn't. Eloquent relationships are loaded in a separate query and there is good reason not to use a join and instead do this with your user relationships as well

Comment: @apokryfos I have tried replacing the join query with with but there seems to be an error with how I have done it. Can u kindly tell me what i have done wrong

Comment: Try replacing the `orWhere($checkClients->whereHas` with just a `->orWhereHas`

Comment: @apokryfos thanks, i believe my issue has been resolved. You might want to post your comments as an answer so that i can mark it as correct

Answer (score 0):

you should join that table to get fields form:

```
   $display_tickets = ManualTicket::select('u.name as name', 'i.name as initiator', 'manual_tickets.status as status', 'manual_tickets.description as description', 'manual_tickets.location as location', 'manual_tickets.created_at as created_at', 'manual_tickets.initiator_id as initiator_id', 'manual_tickets.id as manual_ticket_id','manual_tickets.manual_ticket_log as manual_ticket_log_id',
            'manual_tickets.manual_ticket_log as manual_ticket_log_id')
            ->leftJoin('users as u', 'u.id', '=', 'manual_tickets.user_id')
            ->leftJoin('users as i', 'i.id', '=', 'manual_tickets.initiator_id')
            ->leftJoin('manual_ticket_logs',function ($join){
            $join->on('manual_ticket_logs.manual_ticket_id', '=', 'manual_tickets.id')
                ->on('manual_ticket_logs.id', '=', \DB::raw("(select max(id) from manual_ticket_logs WHERE manual_ticket_logs.manual_ticket_id = manual_tickets.id)"));
            })
            ->where(function ($checkClients) use($target_client_id){
                $checkClients->where('u.client_id', '=', $target_client_id)
                    ->orWhere('i.client_id', '=', $target_client_id);
            })
            ->whereBetween('manual_tickets.created_at', [$start_date->toDateString(), $end_date->addDays(1)->toDateString()])
            ->with('manual_ticket_log')
            ->orderBy("created_at", "DESC")->get();
```

please make sure of the fields names in the newest join clause.

Comment: is there no way to do it leaving it as with?

Comment: the thing is : with in Laravel get info in a separated query, so as far as I know, there is no other straightforward way.

Comment: in that case if i were to use a join, i only want the manual tickets to join with the latest entry in the manual ticket log (as there could be many logs for one particular manual ticket) how can that be done?

Comment: I have updated the code to join the latest row, more inof about joining latest row in:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45570994/10573560

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of Laravel relationships to make the code more readable and avoid an expensive `leftJoin`:

```
 $display_tickets = ManualTicket::select('*')
     ->with([ 'user', 'initiator', 'manual_ticket_log' ])
     ->where(function ($checkClients) use($target_client_id){
         $checkClients->whereHas('user', function ($checkClient) use($target_client_id){
              $checkClient->where('client_id', '=', $target_client_id);
        })->orWhereHas('initiator', function ($checkClient2) use($target_client_id){
              $checkClient2->where('client_id', '=', $target_client_id);
       }));
     })->whereBetween('created_at', [$start_date->toDateString(), $end_date->addDays(1)->toDateString()])
     ->orderBy("created_at", "DESC")
     ->get();
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this

```
    $display_tickets = ManualTicket::select('u.name as name', 'i.name as initiator', 'manual_tickets.status as status', 'manual_tickets.description as description', 'manual_tickets.location as location', 'manual_tickets.created_at as created_at', 'manual_tickets.initiator_id as initiator_id', 'manual_tickets.id as manual_ticket_id','manual_tickets.manual_ticket_log as manual_ticket_log_id')
        ->leftJoin('users as u', 'u.id', '=', 'manual_tickets.user_id')
        ->leftJoin('users as i', 'i.id', '=', 'manual_tickets.initiator_id')
        ->where(function ($checkClients) use($target_client_id){
            $checkClients->where('u.client_id', '=', $target_client_id)
                ->orWhere('i.client_id', '=', $target_client_id);
        })
        ->whereBetween('manual_tickets.created_at', [$start_date->toDateString(), $end_date->addDays(1)->toDateString()])
        ->with(['manual_ticket_log' => function($query) {
                $query->select('field1', 'field2');
          }])
        ->orderBy("created_at", "DESC")->get();
```

Or do this like

```
->with('manual_ticket_log:field1, field2')
```

Comment: I have tried it but same error, manual ticket log column is not found in manual ticket